# Event Listener only updates one user's screen

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am trying to make it so that when a user creates an open game in the game lobby, then their username and a 'join' button will appear on the lobby screen. It works right now, but the problem is it only appears for the user who created the game, it won't appear for any other user, unless another user creates a game too then both of the open games will appear but it doesn't update in real time.

I have it so that when a user creates a game, the game and some varialbes relevant to the game are added into the realtime database. And right now I have an event listener, shown below, checking for whenever the game node is updated, and when it is updated it is supposed to update the UI, but it only does it for the user who made the game.

```
    final RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvfcGames);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    final ArrayList<String> openGames = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, openGames);
    adapter.setClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


  DatabaseReference cgRef = database.getReference("FCGames");
    cgRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            openGames.add("username");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //removeGame();
        }
    });
```

That snippit is functioning because whenever the user creates a game it does add to the list, but I am not sure how to make it so it updates the UI in realtime for every user using the app.

So what should I do to update every users screen in realtime when they are in the lobby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's me again.
I would like to ask where did you add your `addValueEventListener` ?

Confirms all players are listening to the `cgRef`. That makes all of their `onDataChange()`  been called if any field of `cgRef` been changed.

for example :

```
// For all players, listen to the ref in onCreate() of an Activity.
    onCreate(...){
            ...
            cgRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                // update UI in onDataChange()
                // maybe you wand to update your list then adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()
            }
    }

// For creator, write the game's data when the game created.
    createGame(...){
        cgRef.child("someName").setValue(someData);
    }
```

After `cgRef` been updated. Everyone who had `addValueEventListener()` should receive an update.

Comment: Hello again! I have my addValueEventListener in my onCreate method. And I have a setClickListener in the onCreate method as well that is where the cgRef.child...setValue(someData); is executed. How can I make sure that all users are listening to cgRef?

Comment: Hey, actually I just added the adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() and that fixed the problem completely!! Can you explain what that line did?

Comment: Aha, then the problem is in your `recyclerView` not firebase. If you update any data in the list, you should notify him by calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` to let him knows that he need to update his content.